# How to set custom error in php?

Tags: php

I am working on php online testing IDE.

I want to display error like `http://phpfiddle.org/`

Example

**Code**

[image]

**Result**

[image]

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

I want errors without the filepath.

I am trying with `set_error_handler()` but it is not working on `parse error` and `fatal error`.

Comment: I am not sure this is even possible.. to be confirmed. I think you'd have to dig into your server configuration.

Comment: how? i am using php5.5 & Apache 2.2

Comment: As far as I know fatal error have to be catched using try/catch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [register_shutdown_function()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php), then within the called function, you may use [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) for tracing, function, line, code & etc.